# How do you select all elements in the easiest way?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am learning Photoshop CC 2014 and facing a problem exporting the graphical elements to Android assets using PNG Express. The problem is not so much PNG Express. The problem I am having is that I have to select each and every element *manually* before I run the export or else the result of the export will be a few files instead of all the files I need.

If I select a few "groups" like this:

[image]

and expand "PNG:Content" then it looks like this:

[image]

and as you can see "Rectangle 14 copy 3" (as well as other elements) has not been selected!

Is there a way (some keyboard or menu shortcut) to have all elements selected??? I know I'm probably not using the right terminology, so
I've tried to explain myself using these screenshots. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I was under the impression that you can `Extract selected` and `Extract all assets` in PNG Express?

Comment: PNG express works fine, but the process of selecting every element manually before exporting is tedious.

Comment: My point is, according to the video on the website, you can also export all assets and that doesn't require you to select any layers. Sometimes you might want to export just the selected assets and that is fine, but in your description you are making it sound like you have to always select layers before exporting, which is not true. You only need to do that when you want to export specific assets.

Comment: You're right Jonas. My question has more to do with photoshop

Answer (score 1):

That is interesting... I haven't experienced that one before. If you are having problems doing it that way and don't need to do it a lot, you can leave the folders open and hold CTRL and click each layer you want selected... or do what you did and hold CTRL to click the ones it missed. It should work holding SHIFT to click the first item and the last item, highlighting everything in between when expanded I would think... let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: then it would be nice if there was some shortcut to expanding everything so I don't have to do *that* manually...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it works if I do the following:

1. Select all
2. Select all layers
3. Tag (individual layers)
4. Select all
5. Select all layers
6. Export
7. Export all assets